# Apply css with cells generated with POI with the method getPhysicalNumberOfCells?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, apache-poi

I am developing JSF with extender primefaces happens I'm moficando excel I generated default report, I only need to apply the style in the generated cells in detail, I could only style the header.

```
private void columnsCustomers() {
    this.setColumnCustomer(new ArrayList<ValidColumnKey>());        
    this.getColumnCustomer().add(new ValidColumnKey(1, "Codigo", "code"));  
    this.getColumnCustomer().add(new ValidColumnKey(2, "Nombre", "name"));  
    this.getColumnCustomer().add(new ValidColumnKey(3, "Nombre Comercial", "comercialName"));  
    this.getColumnCustomer().add(new ValidColumnKey(4, "Estado", "isActive"));
}

public void postProcessXLS(Object document) {  
    HSSFWorkbook wb = (HSSFWorkbook) document;  
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);  
    //HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet(getCustomer().getName());
    HSSFRow header = sheet.getRow(0);  

    HSSFRow rowUser0  = sheet.createRow((short) 0);

    HSSFCellStyle styleHeader = (HSSFCellStyle) wb.createCellStyle();
    styleHeader.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
    HSSFFont fontHeader = (HSSFFont) wb.createFont();
    fontHeader.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
    fontHeader.setColor(HSSFColor.WHITE.index);
    styleHeader.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.DARK_BLUE.index);          
    styleHeader.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);         
    styleHeader.setFont(fontHeader);
    styleHeader.setBorderBottom((short) 1);
    styleHeader.setBorderLeft((short) 1);           
    styleHeader.setBorderRight((short) 1);
    styleHeader.setBorderTop((short) 1);

    HSSFCell indice = rowUser0.createCell((short) 0);
    indice.setCellValue("N°");
    indice.setCellStyle(styleHeader);

    int nro = 1;
    for(ValidColumnKey column : this.getColumnCustomer()){
        HSSFCell hnro   = rowUser0.createCell((short) nro);
        hnro.setCellValue(column.getDescripcion());
        hnro.setCellStyle(styleHeader);
        nro++;          
    }

    HSSFCellStyle styleCellWhite = (HSSFCellStyle) wb.createCellStyle();
    HSSFFont fontCellWhite = (HSSFFont) wb.createFont();
    fontCellWhite.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_NORMAL);
    styleCellWhite.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    styleCellWhite.setBorderBottom((short) 1);
    styleCellWhite.setBorderLeft((short) 1);            
    styleCellWhite.setBorderRight((short) 1);
    styleCellWhite.setBorderTop((short) 1);

    for(int i=0; i < header.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();i++) {  
        HSSFCell cell = header.getCell(i);    
        cell.setCellStyle(styleHeader);
    }  
}
```

Image: http://s2.subirimagenes.com/otros/previo/thump_8748813excelpoi.jpg

As you see in the image just missing the style that is applied in detailed excel at the edges, I applied the style but apparently does not work, the method will header.getPhysicalNumberOfCells

Could someone guide me, they are much appreciate.

Comment: I also miss you indicate that also want to put the name to the Excel spreadsheet, want to do with this code, but I'm an exception: HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet ("Customer");

Comment: What do you want to do ? The header.getPhysicalNumberOfCells loop iterates each cell of the header (first line in excel), and forces style 'styleHeader' to each cell. This is not necessary because you already do it when creating the header cells. You don'use styleCellWhite either. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your sheet problem : Workbook and sheet are already created by PF at this step. You want probably to simply (re)name the sheet:

```
wb.setSheetName(0, getCustomer().getName());
```

For your other problem (not clear at all at this moment), I suppose you want to format data values, using your style *styleCellWhite*. Here is a way to do it:

```
//iterates lines, then iterate each column giving style to each cell
for (int r=1; r<sheet.getLastRowNum(); r++) {
    HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(r);
    for (int i=0; i<row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); i++) {
        row.getCell(i).setCellStyle(styleCellWhite);
    }
}
```

*Another remark*

You are in a post-process method. This implies that the document, sheet and cells have already been created and filled. You should not create rows or cells, but only modifiy them here (get them and give styles, fix values or titles.).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, of course not you comment I'm generating dynamic table form in rows and columns:

```
<p:dataTable id="listCust" var="cust" value="#{mantClienteMB.customers}" rows="5"
     rowIndexVar="rowIndex" paginatorPosition="top" resizableColumns="true" emptyMessage="">

    <p:column headerText="N°" width="auto">
        <h:outputText value="#{rowIndex+1}" />
    </p:column>
    <c:forEach items="#{mantClienteMB.columnCustomer}" var="colum">
        <p:column headerText="#{colum.descripcion}" width="auto">           
            <h:outputText value="#{cust[colum.entidadBean]}" />                                 
        </p:column>
    </c:forEach>            
</p:dataTable>
```

That means you really have two lists, and I resolved somehow like this:

```
public void postProcessXLS(Object document) {  
    HSSFWorkbook wb = (HSSFWorkbook) document;  
    wb.setSheetName(0, this.getCustomer().getClass().getSimpleName());
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

    sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 1500);
    sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 4500);
    sheet.setColumnWidth(2, 6500);
    sheet.setColumnWidth(3, 6500);
    sheet.setColumnWidth(4, 6500);      

    HSSFRow rowUser0  = sheet.createRow((short) 0);

    HSSFCellStyle styleHeader = (HSSFCellStyle) wb.createCellStyle();
    styleHeader.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
    HSSFFont fontHeader = (HSSFFont) wb.createFont();
    fontHeader.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
    fontHeader.setColor(HSSFColor.WHITE.index);
    styleHeader.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.DARK_BLUE.index);          
    styleHeader.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);         
    styleHeader.setFont(fontHeader);
    styleHeader.setBorderBottom((short) 1);
    styleHeader.setBorderLeft((short) 1);           
    styleHeader.setBorderRight((short) 1);
    styleHeader.setBorderTop((short) 1);

    HSSFCell indice = rowUser0.createCell((short) 0);
    indice.setCellValue("N°");
    indice.setCellStyle(styleHeader);

    int nro = 1;
    for(ValidColumnKey column : this.getColumnCustomer()){
        HSSFCell hnro   = rowUser0.createCell((short) nro);
        hnro.setCellValue(column.getDescripcion());
        hnro.setCellStyle(styleHeader);
        nro++;          
    }

    HSSFCellStyle styleCellWhite = (HSSFCellStyle) wb.createCellStyle();
    HSSFFont fontCellWhite = (HSSFFont) wb.createFont();
    fontCellWhite.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_NORMAL);
    styleCellWhite.setBorderBottom((short) 1);
    styleCellWhite.setBorderLeft((short) 1);            
    styleCellWhite.setBorderRight((short) 1);
    styleCellWhite.setBorderTop((short) 1);

    for (int r=1; r<=this.getCustomers().size(); r++) {
        HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(r);
        for (int i=0; i<row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); i++) {
            row.getCell(i).setCellStyle(styleCellWhite);
        }
    }

}
```